# Dart, why does using innerHtml to set shadow root content work but appendHtml doesn't?

Tags: dart, shadow-dom

I have made [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/0xor1/1c2bca65cce3df8ff315) to show the issue but essentially I have found that using `shadowRoot.innerHtml = '...'` works but using `shadowRoot.appendHtml('...')` doesn't work, it causes the console warning `Removing disallowed element <STYLE>` which I can't explain. Anyone know if this is simple the way it is meant to be or is it specific to Dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Removing disallowed element` indicates that you need a NodeValidator.

```dart
shadowRoot.append(
    new document.body.createFragment('....'), 
    validator: new NodeValidationBuilder().allow(...);
```