# data- attribute in dart dynamic elements

Tags: dart, dart-html, bootjack

I am creating some html elements dynamically with code such as

```dart
new ButtonElement()
```

and its easy to add classes like

```dart
  ..classes.add('dropdown-menu')
```

I want to add the following html to it

```dart
data-toggle="dropdown"
```

but dart doesn't allow me to do so. If I add a `new ElementHtml`  like

```dart
new ElementHtml('<button data-toggle="dropdown"></button>')
```

it says it's invalid. I need it for my bootjack dropdown selector.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a `NodeValidator` that has the `data-toggle` attribute enabled (see also [Dart, why does using innerHtml to set shadow root content work but appendHtml doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000995))

What you can do without `NodeValidator` is

```dart
new ButtonElement()..dataset['toggle'] = 'dropdown';
```