# How to create shadow DOM programmatically in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, shadow-dom

I'm trying to implement the following JS code in Dart way:

Code is taken from here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/

```
<div id="host">Host node</div>
<script>
var root = document.querySelector('#host').createShadowRoot();
root.innerHTML = '<style>' + 
    'button {' + 
      'color: green;' + 
    '}' +
    '</style>' +
    '<content></content>';
</script>
```

I have no doubt that in JS it works ok, but in Dart it fails.
As we know the only one dart script  per document is allowed, so I was forced to place it to the shared dart file:

**main.dart**

```
import 'dart:html';
void main() {
  querySelector('#host').createShadowRoot().appendHtml('<style>' +
    'button {' +
      'color: green;' +
    '}' +
    '</style>' +
    '<content></content>');
}
```

If we try to append any other html tags such as `div`, `ul` etc everything works ok. However in case of `style` and `content` it differs. I get the warning:

```
Removing disallowed element <CONTENT>
Removing disallowed element <STYLE>
```

Please, tell me why?

**Update:**

@GünterZöchbauer Regarding passing the `NodeValidatorBuilder()` to `appendHtml()` method. Please, see the picture: 
[image]

**Final result:**

```
var validator = new NodeValidatorBuilder.common()
  ..allowElement('content', attributes: ['some-attribute', 'some-other'])
  ..allowElement('style');
querySelector('#host').createShadowRoot()
..append(document.body.createFragment('<style>' +
  'button {' +
    'color: green;' +
  '}' +
  '</style>' +
  '<content></content>', validator: validator))
// For illustrative purposes, add the button with some text to test styles
..querySelector('content').append(new ButtonElement()..text = 'Button');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is some default XSS prevention in `dart:html`. You need to pass a NodeValidator to appendHtml which specifies which elements and attributes are allowed.

```dart
var validator new NodeValidatorBuilder.common()
  ..allowElement('content', attributes: ['some-attribute', 'some-other'])
  ..allowElement('style');

... .append(document.body.createFragment(
    '...some html...', validator: validator));
```

Comment: Hm.., appendHtml() can take only one argument. If so where to place `validator` variable?

Comment: I stole it from http://stackoverflow.com/a/24002691/217408 I'm pretty sure I tried it back then. Maybe you need to use another method. I'll have a look...