# Dart + Polymer, how to bind to programmatically generated elements, textarea, select, optgroup

Tags: data-binding, dart, polymer

I'm trying to create a form Polymer component where form elements are generated on the fly. I've looked, and so far the only way to bind the `value` attribute is by using `.injectBoundHtml`. This does not work with all component types, I'm trying to bind the value of a `<textarea>`, and this is what I get:

`Removing disallowed attribute <TEXTAREA value="{{ results[ "comments" ] }}">`

My work around was to add: `textareaID.addEventListener('change', updateValueMap)`

I'm hoping someone could tell me why `value` is disallowed, and/or if there is a better way to **programmatically assign bound attributes in Polymer**. **Please :)!**

Thanks to Gunter's suggestion, and passing a node validator:

```
var val = new NodeValidatorBuilder.common()
  ..allowElement('textarea', attributes:['value']);
this.injectBoundHtml(getElementStr(i), element:selP, validator:val);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textarea doesn't have a `value` attribute. 
Try this instead

```
<textarea>{{results['comments']}}</textarea>
```

For more information about the message `Removing disallowed attribute` see [How to create shadow DOM programmatically in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644253)

Comment: Thank you, but ```<textarea id='comments' >{{ results[ 'comments' ] }}</textarea>``` doesn't work while using ```injectBoundHtml``` . It looks like it only likes to bind attributes, not content.

Comment: I got it working by way of a ```NodeValidatorbuilder```

```var val = new NodeValidatorBuilder.common()
                ..allowElement('textarea', attributes:['value']);
              this.injectBoundHtml(getElementStr(i), element:selP, validator:val);

```